# How can I display data in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to display `Qualified`, `Submitted`, `interviewed`, `Selections`, `Placements` from this json data in Nuxt js.

```
[{
    "Qualified": [{
        "_id": null,
        "count": 2,
        "percentagedata": 0.63
    }],
    "Submitted": [{
        "_id": null,
        "count": 227,
        "percentagedata": 72.29
    }],
    "Interviewed": [{
        "_id": null,
        "count": 58,
        "percentagedata": 18.47
    }],
    "Selections": [{
        "_id": null,
        "count": 4,
        "percentagedata": 1.27
    }],
    "Placements": [{
        "_id": null,
        "count": 16,
        "percentagedata": 5.09
    }]
}]
```

Comment: What did you tried so far ? SO is all about problem solving not for providing the solution from scratch. Can you please post your code which you tried to achieve this for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In vue file

```js
<script>
export default {
  data (){
    return { 
      data: [{
         "Qualified": [{
             "_id": null,
             "count": 2,
         // [...]
         }]
      }]
    } 
  },
  mounted(){
    // DISPLAY IN SCRIPT:
    console.log(this.data[0].Qualified.count)
    
    // DISPLAY ARR NAME:
    console.log(Object.keys(this.data[0])[0]) // should be "Qualified"
    console.log(Object.keys(this.data[0])[1]) // should be "Submitted"

  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div> 
    <!-- DISPLAY IN TEMPLATE -->
    {{ data[0].Qualified.count }}

    <!-- DISPLAY IN ARR NAME -->
    <!-- "Qualified": -->
    {{ Object.keys(data[0])[0] }}
    
   <!-- All in loop: -->
   <div v-for="(value, name) in data[0]">
     {{ name }}
   </div> 

 </div> 
</template>
```

is that it?

Comment: not working  it give full data inside that array

Comment: i just need to display array name

Comment: Edit: like this?